# Interpretation of Incremental Cost-Effectiveness Ratio (ICER) in health economics

Tags: health-insurance, cost-effectiveness

To the health economists in the crowd: Does anyone understand the following passage from [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7567123/pdf/nihms-1558850.pdf)?

> For the first analysis with fixed costs and outcome rates, using the
> $250 and $350/sample cost, there was an increase in the QALYs with
> ICER ranging from $47K-$97K depending on the 5%,10% or 15% admission
> reduction over SOC.

What puzzles me is that they report an ICER in `USD` whereas ICER's should typically be in units of `USD/year`.

In other words, how should one interpret that sentence if one is interested in the cost savings (independently of the variation in admission reduction)?

Comment: @IanCampbell The confusing thing with that table is that it also shows a cost-effectiveness per QALY for the SOC-only, which is strange because SOC-only is supposed to be the benchmark. Isn't the ICER supposed to be relative to that benchmark?

Comment: Put another way: Am I correct to interpret that the SOC+microbiome analysis saves $8922 every year compared to SOC-only (assuming an admission reduction of 5%)?

Comment: @IanCampbell This isn't a literature area I read often or at all, but my overall impression of the depiction of results in the paper is that it's pretty sloppy. The algebra of *"In this study, ICER was calculated as [(CostSOC+Microbialtesting – CostSOC) / (QALYSOC+MicrobialTesting -QALYSOC)]"* seems a bit suspect.

Comment: I also got that impression. The thing is that it's the only reference I found on the cost-saving potential of the microbiome when it comes to diagnostics. Independently of their rigor, what do you think would be the takeaway figure in terms of cost savings? Is it $8922/year/patient?

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, I was just about to type the same quote. It's all a bit suspect the more I read.

Comment: Isn't `ICER = (difference in cost)/(difference in QALY)`?

Comment: @Tfovid I don't get the impression that it's appropriate to take any single number away; my reading of the $8922 number specifically is that this seems like a cost *increase* relative to SOC *for a specific set of assumptions* (cost per sample of $650 and a modest affect on admissions). Savings on average only occurs with cheaper tests or more effective admissions reductions.

Comment: @Tfovid Yes, your understanding of ICER matches mine, the problem is that's not what they wrote. It's possible they made a mistake only in the writeup of the methods and the actual analyses presented are correct, but let's just say that doesn't really encourage confidence in either the authors or the peer review.

Comment: Figures 1 and 2 have some serious https://xkcd.com/833/ problems. I think you have to consider "If the authors are sloppy about their presentation of their work, what else have they missed?" Sometimes physicians are trying to publish papers in a very narrow slice of spare time that they have without any real institutional support for research over patient care, possibly without any real training in research.

Comment: I completely agree about the sloppiness, but I'd still give the authors the benefit of doubt that they haven't pulled the actual numbers out of thin air. I'm just trying to get a ballpark figure (or range) for the cost savings, even if it's completely approximate. The question for me at this stage is how to even interpret the numbers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about medical sciences, rather the economics of health.

Comment: @bob1 I will have to strongly disagree. Healthcare cost-effectiveness research is squarely within the realm of medical science. A question asking about QALYs was literally on my medical board exam. These types of studies are funded by the NIH all the time. See [the AHRQ website](https://www.ahrq.gov/prevention/resources/rice/index.html).

Comment: @IanCampbell If you feel that it is on-topic as a mod, I'm happy to retract my vote.

Comment: @Tfovid I'm not accusing them of pulling numbers out of thin air, but rather I am very familiar with how even minor mistakes and confusion in data analysis can lead to incorrect and misleading results. If you don't understand which numbers go where in an equation, it doesn't matter whether the numbers you plug in came from someplace real or not, the output of the equation is not going to be useful, even for getting a ballpark figure or range.

Comment: @bob1 I don't think it's my place as a mod to determine what's on topic but rather uphold community consensus. If you disagree and feel strongly, I'm happy to post an answer to a Meta question and let the community vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just consider the $250 intervention and 5% reduction in hospitalization.

> For the models, we assumed a 90-day window for 1000
> inpatients and outpatients with cirrhosis.

The authors simulate 2000 total patients for 90 days.

> Health utilities assigned were 1.0 for staying alive without admission/LT, 1.0 for LT, 0.5 for admission and 0.0 for death.

From Table 1, we can learn that with just the standard of care, the 2000 simulated patients would live 1760 quality adjusted life years. Some of them would be hospitalized, making their year of life "worth" half as much. Some would have died, being worth zero.

If there are 2000 patients and they are implementing a $250 intervention it would cost $500000. From Table 1, we can see that they estimate $1200000 in decreased hospitalization / transplant costs (1200000-500000=700000). With that intervention, they assert the simulated patients would experience 11 additional quality adjusted life years.

[image]

- With the standard of care, the 1760 QALYs cost $61400000, $34886/QALY. (something-something rounding)
- With the intervention, the 1771 QALYs cost $60700000, $34274/QALY.

In the methods, they note:

> We calculated QALY (quality of life years) and Incremental cost-effectiveness ratio (ICER). ICER is defined by the difference in cost between two possible interventions, divided by the
> difference in their effect. It represents the average incremental cost associated with 1 additional unit of the measure of effect.

So, the $250 intervention cost $700000 less and made 11 QALY.

- $700000/11QALY = 63636 ≈ 65902 (more something-something rounding)

So they assert that they would save the health system approximately $66000 per quality adjusted life year by implementing the $250 intervention.

So, overall, the authors assert that their intervention not only would make the the population healthier, but that they also saved $700000 over 90 days across 2000 patients. That's $350 per patient.

Comment: Just so that I completely understand the conclusion: For any given patient, the "healthcare system" saves `66000 $/yr * 11 yr = 726000 $` with the proposed microbiome diagnostics compared to the SOC? And that's including the $250 cost of the intervention.

Comment: I worry you might be a bit confused. Remember that a quality adjusted life year is a time period that a person experiences that is weighted (adjusted) based on how good that life year was. Being alive and at home was worth 1 QALY, being admitted was worth 0.5 QALYs, and being dead is worth 0 QALYs. The simulation was 90days (0.25 years), so they must be normalizing the 2000 patients out to a year otherwise how would they get to 1760 QALYs (another strange choice)?

Comment: Yes indeed, I must say I'm totally confused, especially with that "made 11 QALYs", among other things :/

Comment: With just the standard of care, the 2000 patients would live 1760 quality adjusted life years. Some were hospitalized, some died, making their life less "valuable". With the $250 intervention, the 2000 patients would live 1771 quality adjusted life years. Fewer would be hospitalized or die. Thus, 11 quality adjusted life years were created with the intervention.

Comment: The one last thing I find confusing is the time horizon of 90 days, cf. "saved $700000 over 90 days across 2000 patients". Should it be interpreted as `$700000 being saved for 2000 new patients every 90 days`?